# How to create perfectly clean halftones

Tags: image-trace, halftone

I'm trying to figure out, how to recreate the effect used in shapes 2 & 4. 1 and 3 seems to be simple halftones. 1 & 3 though are made with the perfect dots (not like a usual halftone) while they still reflect highlights and shades of the source image.

I have tried to use *Bitmap > Diffusion Dither* and then bring the result to Illustrator, trace it and use *Convert to shape > Ellipse* and it somehow works, but does not produce so neat result as this on the original artwork.

How can I do it cleaner?

[image]

Comment: If anyone is interested, I found another, more flexible solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3a6mfFOLhs

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one:

Stipplism. A live Effects plug-in for Adobe Illustrator CS6 and CC.

You can use the grayscale image or vector to render the effect.

Here is the link:

https://astutegraphics.com/software/stipplism/

[image]